# Unable to return boolean from GPS check

Tags: java, android

Im trying to detect if the GPS on my device is turned on.

Currently i am simply returning a boolean true or false value that then either proceeds with my code, or directs the users to the GPS settings.

At the moment when i return the boolean value my code is crashing. I have debugged it but still cannot see why as it it returning a value.

Here is the code:

```
  GPSYesOrNo g = new GPSYesOrNo(this);

  check = g.checkStatus();
  // check if GPS enabled
  if (check == true) {
     Intent Appoint = new Intent("com.example.flybaseapp.appointmantMenu");
     startActivity(Appoint);
  } else {  
     alert();
  }
```

And the GPSYesOrNo class:

```
public class GPSYesOrNo {
   Context cc;
   private LocationManager locationManager;
   boolean enable;

   public GPSYesOrNo(Context c) {
      this.cc = c;
      checkStatus();
   }

   public boolean checkStatus() {
      locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 

      if (enabled) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Post the logcat please.

Comment: Is `locationManager` assigned? Show us the code.

Comment: @323go I have added the whole class. I have a declared location manager object

Comment: Why are you extending `Activity`? This seems pointless, especially since you're also passing in a `Context` -- which an `Activity` actually extends. How are you invoking `GPSYesOrNo`? If it's an activity, you can't just create it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not extend Activity, just pass in a context to be able to obtain a locationManager. Anyway your app crashed because you do not call the contructor with the context parameter. Thus cc is null. By the way getSystemService(cc.LOCATION_SERVICE) should be getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)

Change

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

to

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) cc.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i see what you're saying about passing the context. I changed it back to not having the acitivity class and have edited my code. I pass the context when creating the instance of the class then simply call the method through the constructor. at the moment I am still receiving an error stating that 'The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type GPSYesOrNo'

Comment: you have to prefix the call with the context passed in the constructor. Something like ctx.getSystemService() where ctx is the context pass in.

Comment: Nyguyen Many thanks it is working. Cant believe i managed to get just a simple constructor object so messed up. Again thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning enable, not comparing:

```
if(enable = true)
```

Change it to `==` instead and you should be good.  Like other people said, also, `if (enable)` would look much cleaner.

**Update:**

With the new information, it seems your locationManager is null when you're calling isProviderEnabled on it.  Verify that it's set correctly before calling checkStatus().

Comment: Good catch. You could also do, `if (enable)` which is cleaner and more standard, in my opinion, but either will work

Comment: Actually, `return enable;` would be the cleanest.

Comment: @mjuarez Completely see what you youmean on that silly mistake. Sadly i am still getting an error. I have added the logcat